# Tomcat 7 Maven plugin running differrent version of Tomcat

Tags: java, macos, maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I installed Tomcat 7.0.59 in OSX, however when running the maven plugin it says it's running 7.0.47 and it creates a new tomcat directory in target with some new configuration.
I just want it to run the version I had installed in the machine, to use the config under $CATALINA_HOME/conf and to deploy the app to $CATALINA_HOME/webapps as normal.

Here is the message when running the plugin:

```
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/xxx
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at /Users/abc/xxx/target/tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /xxx
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Mar 19, 2015 3:12:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Mar 19, 2015 3:12:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

It creates the following structure:

```
target/tomcat//conf:
logging.properties tomcat-users.xml   web.xml

target/tomcat//logs:
access_log.2015-03-19

target/tomcat//webapps:

target/tomcat//work:
Tomcat

target/tomcat//work/Tomcat:
localhost

target/tomcat//work/Tomcat/localhost:
xxx

target/tomcat//work/Tomcat/localhost/xxx:
```

Here is the config of the plugin:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <server>localhost</server>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is the output from /Library/Tomcat/bin/version.sh:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Server built:   Jan 28 2015 15:51:10 UTC
Server number:  7.0.59.0
OS Name:        Mac OS X
OS Version:     10.10.2
Architecture:   x86_64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_40-b25
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: The tomcat7-maven-plugin is _designed_ to run an embedded Tomcat. That is what it does! You can ask it to deploy an application to an extant Tomcat instance using the [deploy goal](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html), but this does not start Tomcat. Maven is not supposed to start external services, this is not what Maven does - and the plugins follow this design.

Comment: thanks. In that case how would be possible to copy the files in $CATALINA_HOME/conf to target/tomcat/conf?

Comment: Yes, please read the documentation. There are a large number of config options. You are looking for [`additionalConfigFilesDir`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-war-mojo.html#additionalConfigFilesDir).

Answer (score 3):

Reason behind is that the maven plugin downloads its own version of tomcat (which has nothing to do with your locally installed tomcat).

The `tomcat7-maven-plugin` v. `2.2` has a dependency on Tomcat v. `7.0.47`.

The [tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.tomcat.maven%7Ctomcat7-maven-plugin%7C2.2%7Cmaven-plugin) references the parent project [tomcat-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.tomcat.maven%7Ctomcat-maven-plugin%7C2.2%7Cpom) which itself defines the version of tomcat being used (which is `<tomcat7Version>7.0.47</tomcat7Version>`). Just look at the POM XML's.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest version of Tomcat (8.0.20) , start it manually and then run the Tomcat 7 maven plugin without any problems.I have an article with complete instructions at my blog (http://blog.devcanvas.org/deploy-a-web-application-from-the-command-line-by-using-tomcat-maven-plugin/).
Try to use brew for Tomcat and for maven.